# How to write multiple where conditions in single where condition in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using multiple where conditions in my query it's working fine but i need to refactor the code is there any way to write both conditions in one where condition..

```
DB::table('books')->where('user_id',$uID)->where('author',$author_name)->delete();
```

Comment: there is no need to refactor that. it will make the code less readable and so less maintainable. What you could do is replace `DB::table('books')` with `Book::` so you can trace the use of the class `Book` with your IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass array of conditions to the where function.

```
DB::table('books')->where([['user_id','=',$uID],['author','=',$author_name]])->delete();
```

As per Doc :

> pass an array of conditions to the where function. Each element of the
> array should be an array containing the three arguments typically
> passed to the where method

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

You can use array in where function like below -

```
Modelname::where([['user_id',$uID],['author',$author_name]])->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DB::table('books')->where(function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', $uID);
    $q->where('author',$author_name);
})->delete();
```

BTW you can change "DB::table('books')->" with "Book::" if you have Book model